# Accessing "polymer serve" from WLAN via 192.168.0.x:8080 on Windows 10

Tags: polymer-serve

I am having problem accessing `polymer serve` from WLAN via local IPv4 address on port 8080 on Windows 10.

I have open up the port 8080 on Windows Firewall for TCP, but it doesn't resolve the problem.

I can access 127.0.0.1:8080 on local machine, but fail to access 192.168.0.x (i.e. local IPv4 address) from the same local machine on my web browser. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

use `polymer serve -H 0.0.0.0`

`polymer serve` defaults to `localhost` which typically is `127.0.0.1` only.